# Keyboard doesn't insert space when 'ctrl' or 'shift' pressed

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have a short question and hope someone out there can help me with that kind of problem.

I've reinstalled a fresh Freya on my Laptop, everything runs without problems (as it did before) and smooth so far, there's only one thing that's IMO a *huge* no-go (when writing a text / while coding) :

When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> and while holding one of this keys pressed and try to make a space it doesn't do anything, this wasn't in my previous freya installation. Does anybody know how I can fix this / get it back as it was before? (That it'll insert a space even while holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>)

Would be awesome if someone out there can help me, had some thoughts that it's maybe something to configure with dconf if it isn't in the switchboard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was already able to solve that bug by disabling the ibus

Comment: OP, if you were able to address the issue, please post your solution as an answer below